# item not found in the collection on second loop

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2007

I am trying to compare all of the field values between to tables and return the entire record from both tables when it finds values that dont match

it works fine on the first run through, but as soon as it goes into the second loop i get iten not found in this collection at

```
If rs1.Fields(fld) <> rs2.Fields(fld) Then
```

This is the code i have in the section right now:

```
Private Sub Execute_Click()
DoCmd.RunSQL "Delete * FROM Issues2"
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim fld As DAO.Field

'.... set those recordsets via SQL statements
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Full")
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Transaction1")
For Each fld In rs1.Fields
    If rs1.Fields(fld) <> rs2.Fields(fld) Then
        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Issues2 SELECT Full.* FROM Full LEFT JOIN Transaction1 ON Full.[Member ID] = Transaction1.[Member ID] WHERE (((Transaction1.[Member ID]) Is Null));"
        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Issues2 SELECT Transaction1.* FROM Transaction1 LEFT JOIN Full ON Transaction1.[Member ID] = Full.[Member ID] WHERE (((Full.[Member ID]) Is Null));"
    End If
Next fld
```

does anyone have any idea why it would work fine on first run but on the second loop it errors out?

Comment: It may help for you to post the code that CALLS this routine (twice).  Also this suggestion:  between the first and second call, insert `DoEvents` and see if the behavior changes.

Comment: the code is just attached to a click event, as soon as i click the button this is what runs. as for the DoEvents, where would i put those? Im brand new to VBA so I dont know probably 90% of the terms for everything or what they do

Comment: Search Net on "Microsoft Access compare tables"; check out results such as http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showpost.php?p=642465&postcount=12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You logic is missing something critical.  It looks like you may be wanting something like:

```
For Each fld1 In rs1.Fields
 For Each fld2 In rs2.Fields
  If fld1.Name = fld2.Name Then
    If fld1 <> fld2 Then
        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Issues2 ...;"
        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Issues2 ...;"

    End If

  End If
 Next fld2
Next fld1
```

**Code above corrected 3/5 4:45 PM CST**

Note `fld` is declared for `rs1`, but you are trying to invoke it for `rs2` as well.  Code above proposes separate Field variables, `fld1` and `fld2`.

You're slinging those recordsets around pretty freely.  Try:

```
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Full", dbOpenSnapshot)
```

That way there is no danger of `rs1` trying to respond to changes.  Also, adding `DoEvents` can clear up some issues (though I try to reserve its use for provisional debugging... and in your situation, it is not relevant given the logic issues already cited):

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Issues2 ...;"
DoEvents
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Issues2 ...;"
DoEvents
```

You have another serious problem with the original code.  Your SQL queries do not make use of the variables.  That is, you are running the *identical* query repeatedly instead of one that is dynamically changed.  As far as I can figure out, that defeats the purpose.

Comment: shouldnt 
    For Each fld1 In rs1.Fields
    For Each fld2 In rs1.Fields
be fld1 in rs1 and fld2 in rs2? otherwise theres no mention of rs2 anywhere in the code?

Comment: if i use that code and change the second for each to fld2 in rs2, i get a compile error saying "next without for"

Comment: I had just noticed the typo.   Glad you caught it too.  The compile error is some straightforward syntax problem; I don't see the issue from here, but it will work out.

Comment: ok, i fixed that, now i gotta figure out the insert command because it wont add rows after that command runs the first time, apparently i have to do something about closing and re opening hte recordset after every insert?

Comment: Did you get that solved?  If not, let us know the precise point where the error is raised and what it is reporting.

Comment: its running through the code now, but it isnt moving anything into the  issues table. When i step through the execution it hits Next fld1 then goes back to If fld1 <> fld2 Then, so it looks like its not changing the field its looking at in the second table. Even if thats the case it should be copying every record since only the first loop will have matching values that it bypasses and the rest wont match so it should copy the entire record from full and transaction tables into the issues table

Comment: hmmm, its still pulling every record, and apparently multiple times. I interupted it and its still at 275k records even tho it shouldnt be more than 8. so its ignoring the "not equal" part and it seems to be looping through multiple times somehow.... this program is making me a sad panda this week

Comment: Do you know how to set a Break Point and use `Debug.Print` to dump values into the Immediate Window? If not, look up info about those tools before going further.

Comment: it looks like fld1 starts in the correct place but never advances because next fld2 is before next fld1 so it never makes it to next fld 1? so how would i fix that. Also fld2 works, its just starting in the middle of my table (row 606 to be exact) for some reason

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49167/discussion-between-smandoli-and-user1787114)